# What does the phrase "improve one's decision making" in this sentence refer to?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, sentence-meaning

> The expectation of intelligent gossip is a powerful motive for serious
>   self-criticism, more powerful than New Year resolutions to improve
>   one’s decision making at work and at home.

What does "improve one's decision making" in the above sentence refer to - "expectation of intelligent gossip" or "New Year resolutions"?

Is there a general rule of thumb to identify what phrases such as this, refer to? Also will there be any change in the meaning if a comma is introduced between "resolutions" and "to"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That phrase is a part the *whole* clause used for comparison: **'New Year resolutions *to improve one’s decision making* at work and at home'** - which is suggested as an example of self-criticism (= some people promise on the New Years Eve to take *better* decisions 'from now on', and that promise becomes a *motive* for them, which is 'less powerful' in terms of the whole sentence). So the answer is: that phrase is related to 'New Year resolutions'.

The comma you keep in mind, *technically*, would **change** the sense, since if we exclude the (specializing) phrase 'more powerful than New Year resolutions' between the two commas, the sentence will stay (almost) grammatical:

> The expectation of intelligent gossip is a powerful motive for serious
>   self-criticism, (a motive) to improve one’s decision making at work
>   and at home.